# Port redirection

Tags: mysql, linux, centos, firewall

I have the following scenario:

I changed the port of MySQL 54235, on linux server Centos, I accept connections from outside only on that port.

I have an old and discontinued third-party software, where there is no option to change the default port 3306. However, this software should access 2 fixed external ips.

How do I configure on linux to accept connection on port 3306 only from these 2 fixed ips, and internally, redirect the connection to port 54235?

Comment: Should be pretty easy to do with a few iptables rules. [Starting point](https://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/NAT-HOWTO-6.html#ss6.2)

Answer (score 2):

the most easy is to use "socat"

> socat TCP-LISTEN:3306,fork TCP:127.0.0.1:54235

Comment: I need to block access on port 3306 to other ips and release only 2, how do I do this?